# lr_xml_get_value function fails

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, loadrunner

I have this SOAP Response from testing with HP LoadRunner 12.53.  I need to extract a value can keep getting "No Matches were Found for the specific query" using the lr_xml_get_values function:

```
lr_xml_extract("XML={RESPONSE}",
       "XMLFragmentParam=OutputParam",
        "Query=/Envelope/Body/TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM/RequestID/text()",
        LAST);
```

Here is my response:

```
"RESPONSE" =  "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <timeexpresp:TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM xmlns:timeexpresp="http://esoa.census.gov/soa/CanonicalModel/Core/CDM/TimeExpenseCDM/V1">
      <meta:RequestID xmlns:meta="http://esoa.census.gov/soa/CanonicalModel/Core/Common/V1">**N53e79c17.N60c0f9d8.7.15de03dae49.N3fbe**</meta:RequestID>
    </timeexpresp:TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

I need to extract the RequestID value in **BOLD**  Any help??

Comment: Apologies - I meant to add this function as my problem:
  
    lr_xml_get_values("XML={RESPONSE}",
          "ValueParam=OutputParam",
          "Query=/Envelope/Body/timeexpresp:TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM",
          LAST);

Comment: Of the top of my head, you are using Envelope and Body without the namespace but TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentC‌​BM with the namespace. Did you try just ignoring the namespaces?

Comment: Yes..  still doesn't work.  Get same error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
char * xml_input = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
 "<soapenv:Body>"
    "<timeexpresp:TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM xmlns:timeexpresp=\"http://esoa.census.gov/soa/CanonicalModel/Core/CDM/TimeExpenseCDM/V1\">"
      "<meta:RequestID xmlns:meta=\"http://esoa.census.gov/soa/CanonicalModel/Core/Common/V1\">**N53e79c17.N60c0f9d8.7.15de03dae49.N3fbe**</meta:RequestID>"
    "</timeexpresp:TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM>"
  "</soapenv:Body>"
"</soapenv:Envelope>";

Action() {

 int i, NumOfValues;
 char buf[64];

 lr_save_string(xml_input, "XML_Input_Param"); // Save input as parameter

 lr_xml_extract("XML={XML_Input_Param}",
      "XMLFragmentParam=Result", 
      "Query=/Envelope/Body/TimeExpenseAcknowledgmentCBM/RequestID/text()", LAST );

 lr_output_message(lr_eval_string("Extracted: {Result}"));

 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Action.c(19): "lr_xml_extract" succeeded, 1 match processed
Action.c(23): Extracted: **N53e79c17.N60c0f9d8.7.15de03dae49.N3fbe**
```

Comment: I'm not sure why... but your solution didn't work for me :(  I copied exactly as shown into a new script.. but I get No Matches Found still.

Comment: Strange... I don't know why it didn't work for you. I am on 12.55 though